What was the first multi core CPU?
What was the first CPU which was capable of running two independent instructions in parallel? The commonly given answer is the IBM POWER4 but that's likely incorrect because the Sun MAJC 5200 was, to quote the announcement "two VLIW (very long instruction word) microprocessors on a single piece of silicon".

Please define "capable of running two independent instructions in parallel" better. For example the Pentium released in 1993 can execute two unrelated instructions at the same time as it has two execution pipelines where one is capable of executing all instructions and the other just simple instructions, on single thread. POWER4 released in 2001 was just the first non-embedded processor with two CPU cores on a single die so can run two threads.

Hrm, how do we put this. Could be independently programmed with the same instruction set?

To save everybody else the effort: although there were three separate 1990s consoles with multiple programmable cores that underwent silicon consolidation for cost reduction, none seems to have merged its two processors. I checked: the Mega Drive, SNES and Saturn.

The question title and body do not match.  The body is apparently asking about instruction-level parallelism (for which see the 6600, Stretch,etc), whereas the title requires entire execution context.  Please clarify which you intend.

Additionally, the wording suggests you are only interested in answers where the processor is a "single IC" (possibly stretched to include multiple chips in a single carrier) and not earlier computers. Is this your aim?

This is a related question (though not a dup).

@chx - please come back and edit your question for clarity so it doesn't get closed - there's a perfectly reasonable question here if you'd be more specific.

(BTW: I wish there was a rule on SO that a question that attracts close vote for lack of clarity would stay open for 24hrs or even 48hrs even if the vote threshold was met.  Sometimes - frequently! - the OP can't get back in a shorter amount of time.  The question gets closed and it's a hassle to reopen it.  Give the OP a chance!  It isn't a dup or multiple-questions-in-one.  It's totally fixable even if the OP can't hang around his computer 24/7 in order to fix it up. Also this questioner has provided us with good questions and answers.  He's not a newbie or troll.  Don't pull the trigger!)

@davidbak In this case it maybe should have been closed until the OP read up on taxonomy enough to figure out what they wanted to ask.  We now have answers suggesting barrel processors (like an 1c8t Honewell or 1c10t CDC 6500) which are similar to SMT / Hyperthreading, Raffzahn starting out with IBM S/360 65MP which is two processors in one cabinet(?), and stuff like that.  The OP's question-body definition still includes superscalar uniprocessor machines like P5 Pentium that can run independent instructions from the same instruction stream.

Pentium 4 with Hyperthreading was an early superscalar SMT, 1c2t, which could sent uops from separate logical cores to execution units in the same clock cycle.  So even a definition that required 2 separate execution contexts / instruction-streams wouldn't be what's normally meant by "multi-core" (separate physical cores, each capable of fetching machine code and executing instructions independently of the others, not sharing any execution resources except maybe cache.  AMD Bulldozer is a halfway case with FP/SIMD units shared by pairs of weak integer cores.)

Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide! is a very good article and covers scalar pipelines, superscalar, SMT, and multi-core; should give you a better understanding of the taxonomy.  https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/ is a deep-dive on Bulldozer, and interesting design (which didn't turn out very efficient) with pairs of physical cores sharing some resources.

The question is hard to answer, as all used are weakly defined generic terms, which are usually not useful when it comes to asking for a 'first', as the world itself is marching in parallel, so many similar developments happen at the same time.
A question like that needs very definitions for the item asked to distinguish from similar. But for the fun of it, let's see what could be found matching the question as it is:

What was the first multi core CPU?

What is a core and what is a CPU?
By assuming core as a complete processor, and CPU as central processing unit, then I give you the 1965 IBM 360 Model 65MP. One CPU with two processors working on the same memory running a single OS flipping processes on demand between them.

What was the first CPU which was capable of running two independent instructions in parallel?

Well, wouldn't that already cover any CPU having a notable (*1) pipeline? I would think any processor featuring a pipeline that carries more than none instruction at a time and operates on part of them (like address calculation for parameters) during its stages. In that case we can take the very same Model 65 (with or without MP). It also had for example two independent address calculation units working in parallel.

The commonly given answer is the IBM POWER4

Isn't a 2001 Chip rather late? And while the POWER 4 is a nice example of scheduling single instructions onto multiple execution units, it's still just one processor.
Only its MCM package held up to 4 POWER4 chips/dies (plus RAM) in a single package.
Which nicely shows the same point as the IBM 360/65M:
When is multi-core multi-core?

More than one in the same row of cabinets?
More than one in the same cabinet?
More than one on the same board?
More than one in the same module?
More than one in the same 'chip type' module?
More than one the same die?

Maybe you want to specify exactly which one.
(Also, if going with either, why that and not one above or below as well?)

but that's likely incorrect because the Sun MAJC 5200 was, to quote the announcement "two VLIW (very long instruction word) microprocessors on a single piece of silicon".

The 1999 announced MAJC 5200 would fit the very last category of two processors on one die. But so did the 1984 Rockwell R65C29 Dual CMOS Microprocessor. Yes, that are two standard 6502 in the same package on the same die using the same bus to access the same memory (*2). The R65C29 with full 64Ki external address is not an embedded system (*3,4).
Not to mention that, again, the "on a single piece of silicon" is a quite arbitrary distinction considering that modern processors are more often than not following IBM's MCM type packaging of multiple dies, often manufactured in different processes onto a single chip carrier - which itself is a chip die :))

Long story short: Please specify exactly what you're looking for and make sure the terms used do mean what you think they means.

*1 - No, the 6502 doesn't really have a pipeline, just a prefetch of the next instruction, something next to every CPU of that time did.
*2 - Plus a handful of private ports for each so startup sequence as well as processor to processor communication can be done effectively.
*3 - Although almost exclusive used in embedded systems, the R65C29 is not an embedded conroler. The embedded version would be the R65C00/21 device with on board RAM and ROM.
*4 - Maybe as interesting the why-on-earth-did-they-do-it? After all, a 1..4 MHz 6502 wasn't exactly top notch in 1984, not even with two cores. It resolves to the same idea as the MAJC: thread level parallelism. Handling two interrupt driven thread on a single core brings comes with a lot of overhead, even on a simple 3 register CPU like the 6500. In such an environment two slower CPUs sharing the load can be way more performant than a single core switching all the time. One reason why the R65C00/21 thrived in communications and Rockwell created new offspring way into the 2000s.

The KDF9 (1963) CPU had two separate execution units, master control and arithmetic control, which handled different classes of instruction.  Not so much 'pipelining' as division of labour.

@dave yes, another parti(ioned)al example how above question can be answered..

"What is a core?" - my recollection is that Intel invented that term when they introduced a device with two independent "instruction stream executors" in one socket. Before then we called an instruction stream executor a "processor".  Intel wanted that word to equal the device they sold ("a Pentium processor") and so used the word "core".  (Before then, cores were just magnetized doughnuts)

@dave Then again, they degraded any use as technical term them self by using it as a marketing name got their following devices. Essentially making it meaningless without further specification.

"[...] with full 64Ki external address [...]" <-- Did you meant "KiB"?

@IsmaelMiguel No, they are 64 Ki addresses. Bytes is what they are used for to address. A subtile but important difference.

@Raffzahn I wasn't familiar with the term, and genuinely though it was a mistake. But good thing I asked, thank you. Maybe it is a good idea to add a note, like how you did in other places, so others don't think the same and don't edit your answer?

I'm going to nominate the Control Data CDC 6500. No, that's not a typo. Not its more famous brother the 6600, but the 6500.
It was announced in 1964, and (unlike the 6600) had a dual pipeline CPU, vaguely like the Pentium D did (though obviously much later). It was pretty much two CDC 6400 CPUs connected to a single memory system.
Compared to the IBM 360 model 65 MP, the real question would be dates. The CDC 6500 was announced in 1964, but wasn't delivered until 1967. The 360 Model 65 MP was announced in 1965. I haven't been able to find a record of when it was first delivered, but there was a couple of year gap there, so it's entirely possible it was delivered first, even though it wasn't announced until a little later.

This points out another fuzziness around the question - when we are asking about "the first" anything, when do we consider it to really exist?  (I'd say when the feature of interest works, which often cannot be known to us).

What do you mean by "dual pipeline CPU"?  Pentium D was two physical cores in the same package.  Initially technically on the same silicon instead of a multi-chip module, as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_D says the 90 nm version used two single-core dies that were adjacent on the original wafer.  But they can still only talk to each other via the frontside bus.  Anyway, the cores supported SMT (Hyperthreading), so it was 2c4t in a single socket.  CDC 65/6600 were barrel processors, like 1c10t, so more like single-core 1c2t P4, from 2002.

(And of course each physical core in a Pentium D was superscalar with two double-speed integer ALU ports, plus load and store execution units and SIMD/FP etc.  You don't mean "dual" in that sense, do you, of being able to start 2 independent add instructions from the same instruction stream in the same clock cycle?)

@PeterCordes: The PP/PPU was a barrel processor. But on the 6500, the CPU had two concurrent pipelines (i.e., you basically had a pair of 6400 CPUs connected to the same memory). It could start 2 add instructions in a single cycle, but not from the same instruction stream.

Oh, I see. So you do mean true multiprocessing in the same sense as S/360 65MP.

@PeterCordes: Yes, the two were very similar. I've reworded a bit to attempt to clarify.

You just missed your chance to own one.

@dave: Dang! And I even had a spare quarter of a million dollars laying around with nothing to spend it on too!

Honeywell 800 - was not "the first CPU which was capable of running two independent instructions in parallel".
It could do 8 ⇐ EIGHT.
Classified (now) as a "barrel processor" it had 8 completely independent register sets and would switch from one thread to another at every instruction.
P.S. That wikipedia article linked above ("barrel processor") says the CDC 6000 series was earlier but I don't know anything about those; if someone else wants to write an answer about them, that would be great.
P.P.S. I never actually directly used a Honeywell 800.  Only indirectly: A Honeywell 800 cut my paychecks for almost 2 years.  (When I was working for Honeywell's Marine System Division, West Covina, CA, in the late 1970s a Honeywell 800 was their "IT department"'s machine.  (We were using Honeywell 716s - 16 bit minicomputer - on the project I was on.  50 of them, with primitive home-grown networking, for a Navy sonar trainer.)
P.P.P.S. Someone might quibble that a hardware round-robin approach to multithreading is not running independent instructions "in parallel".  To everyone else out there besides the OP: I don't care. Hardware multithreading of this kind is "in parallel" whether or not electrons are flowing simultaneously for two different instructions.  Because you have to code your program the same way, regardless. (Also, OP can clarify his question should he choose to.)

I thought about including it in my answer, but it definitly does not work really two instructions in parallel. A barrel processor executes interleaved, one at a time, then the next, for all of its 8 'virtual' processors. They feel like dedicated ones but the real processor hardware is time shared. Any yes, the CDC is the same in with 10 virtual processors. Their job is to maintain feed and comfort the FPU unit, so it could go at maximum speed. A very nifty concept.

A barrel processor is more like SMT (Simultaneous MultiThreading), multiple execution contexts on the same physical core.  In modern terminology, that's a 1c8t machine: 1 physical core, 8 logical cores.  That's still interesting and as you say can give better utilization for an FPU, especially if it's pipelined with highish latency, but multi-core in the same sense as  POWER4 would mean at least 2c2t.  (The OP's current definition is super broken and includes any superscalar 1c1t like 1993's P5 Pentium, so I'm discounting that.)

No, no it isn't the same. Dekker's algorithm will succeed on such an architecture but will fail on a true multiprocessor.

Offered as a potential candidate, depending on the definition we adopt: the Intel 8271, ostensibly a floppy disk controller from 1977, is actually a dual-core microcontroller with an appropriate embedded ROM.

Great reminder.

The Inmos Transputer
If you're happy for "CPU" to not be limited by a single piece of silicon, the Transputer is your beastie.
The entire concept behind the Transputer was distributed processing. The chips were explicitly designed for parallelism, so that the same parallel-processing code could be run (with time slicing) on a single core or be spread over multiple cores. This definitely made the "CPU" the combination of all cores, with a single executable covering all the cores.
The Transputer anticipated pretty much all the modern issues of multi-core processing, 20 years before multi-core PCs arrived. Unfortunately their existence was predicated on the idea that clock rates would limit how much performance a single core could manage. Whilst this assumption was correct, it was several orders of magnitude and a couple of decades before this became true, and the Transputer by that point was long dead.

If we broaden the definition to include any multiprocessor shared-memory system, yes that includes stuff like multi-socket 486 and Pentium (and RISCs) from the 1990s, but also includes what Raffzahn's answer starts with: IBM 360 Model 65MP from 1965, long before the 1984 release of Transputer.  (Was it the first SMP using microprocessors?  The first using cheap microprocessors?)

The topic and the body of the question may have different answers.
To be fair, the POWER4 CPU is said to be the first non-embedded multicore microprocessor with two cores on the same die.
It might also mean that the MAJC 5200 was the first two-core microprocessor, but embedded one. It is basically a System-on-Chip (SoC) with even a GPU preprocessor onboard the die. It might not count as a generic non-embedded microprocessor.
